# Is it possible to use Oracle Wallet for node connection to its vault?

Tags: corda

Is it possible to start an enterprise node, using an **Oracle 12c** backed up 
vault configured via Oracle Wallet (i.e., configure the **`node.conf`** using only a
`dataSource.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:@`**`SOME_ORACLE_WALLET_TNS`**`"` without
specifying any `dataSource.username` or `dataSource.password` parameters ) ?

In this case, please inform which additional oracle `.jar` files should be
added to the node drivers dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle wallet is supported in Corda Enterprise. Below is a working configuration with Oracle Wallet, and has been tested with Oracle 11g and Oracle 12c.

**Prerequisites**

1. Oracle wallet is configured with auto login (`-auto_login_local`) for the node's database
2. Assuming that the node's database connection URL is configured in `tnsnames.ora`, with alias `"db11g"`:

   ```
   $ echo 'For JDBC URL ==> "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe" ==> below is an example of tnsnames.ora'
   $ cat ~/oracle_experiment/tnsnames.ora 
   db11g =
     (DESCRIPTION =
       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
       (CONNECT_DATA =
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = xe)
       )
     )
   ```
3. Wallet location is configured in `sqlnet.ora`:

   ```
   $ cat ~/oracle_experiment/sqlnet.ora
   WALLET_LOCATION =
      (SOURCE =
        (METHOD = FILE)
        (METHOD_DATA =
          (DIRECTORY = /Users/corda/oracle_wallet/)
        )
      )

   SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE = TRUE
   SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
   SSL_VERSION = 0
   ```
4. Sqlplus should be able to login without a password challenge:

   ```
   sqlplus /@db11g     
       SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Tue Nov 27 15:17:00 2018 
       Copyright (c) 1982, 2017, Oracle.  All rights reserved. 
       Last Successful login time: Tue Nov 27 2018 14:46:09 +08:00 
       Connected to:   
       Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production  
       SQL>
   ```

**Necessary steps**

1. Change the database-specific configuration from:

   ```
   $ cat dbconfig_oracle11g.conf
   dataSourceProperties = {
       dataSourceClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       dataSource.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
       dataSource.user = corda_es_user
       dataSource.password = corda_es_passwd
   }
   ```

   To

   ```
   $ cat dbconfig_oracle_wallet.conf 
   dataSourceProperties = {
       dataSourceClassName = "oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
       dataSource.url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:/@db11g"
       dataSource.user=null
       dataSource.password=null   // user and password can't be ignored and can't be left blank.
   }
   ```
2. Download and copy the following JARs into the node's `drivers` folder:

   ```
   ]$ ls <corda>/drivers/
   ojdbc8.jar
   osdt_cert.jar
   osdt_core.jar
   oraclepki.jar
   ```
3. Start the node with the `oracle.net.wallet_location` and `oracle.net.tns_admin` options:

   ```
   ]$ java -Doracle.net.wallet_location=/Users/corda/oracle_wallet/ -Doracle.net.tns_admin=/Users/corda/oracle_experiment/ -jar corda.jar
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [SSL with JDBC](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) blog for more details.

Comment: This suggestion is highly generic. It does not give more details than Joel's answer regarding Oracle Wallet use with Corda.